# Spring autowires beans in different order when running from jar vs IntelliJ - Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler' No handlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, classpath

I am building a spring web socket app and I am facing the following issue.

When I am running the app using IntelliJ everything is fine and the app starts up just fine.

When I am building the fat jar with spring boot maven plugin and starting up the app using `java -jar` the app is failing to start with the following error

`Failed to start bean 'subProtocolWebSocketHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No handlers`

at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler:start()

My spring web socket config looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    private WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats;

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
                .setHeartbeatValue(new long []{webSocketsProperties.getClientHeartbeatsSecs() * 1000, webSocketsProperties.getServerHeartbeatsSecs() * 1000})
                .setTaskScheduler(heartBeatScheduler());

        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setWebSocketMessageBrokerStats(WebSocketMessageBrokerStats webSocketMessageBrokerStats) {
        this.webSocketMessageBrokerStats = webSocketMessageBrokerStats;
    }
}
```

The reason why the above error is happening is because when I run the app using the jar the method

```
@Autowired(required = false)
public void setConfigurers(List<WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer> configurers) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(configurers)) {
        this.configurers.addAll(configurers);
    }
}
```

inside DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration which is supposed to autowire my `WebSocketConfig` is invoked after the

```
@Override
protected void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    for (WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer configurer : this.configurers) {
        configurer.registerStompEndpoints(registry);
    }
}
```

in DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration which is causing the `no handlers` error. When I am starting the app through IntelliJ this is happening in reverse and everything is fine.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and what might be the reason causing it?

Is there any chance that loading classpath is happening in a different order in a jar vs in IntelliJ and that confuses spring?

---

EDIT

My `WebSocketConfig` class is slightly different than what I have put above. I am autowiring `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` in it with setter injection. I have updated the code above. The reason why I didn't put this in my initial question is that I thought it was insignificant. But it is not. Answer is coming below...

Thanks a lot in advance

(let me know if you want more technical details from my side)

Nick

Comment: I can see `WebSocketConfig` class in annotated with `@Configuration`. It qualifies for `@Component` or `@Service` class,

Comment: as a result it should be autowired as a bean in the `setConfigurers` list right?

Comment: Yes, It will not solve ur problem, but since you are autowiring, it should be Component

Comment: `@Autowired(required = false)` why is it not required?

Comment: Not sure why spring has it as optional. I did override the method and made it required but  didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

So after playing around with my code I figured out that the issues is the injection of the `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` bean. Apparently this is causing `WebSocketConfig` bean (which is a special type of config since it implements `WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`) to be ready at a later stage in the Spring Context Initialisation leaving `List<WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer> configurers` empty when it is checked by the `registerStompEndpoints()`.

So the solution was to create a second configuration class and move the `WebSocketMessageBrokerStats` bean and all the operations on it in the new config file.

The above is fixing the jar file and I am able to run it with `java -jar`, however I have no idea how IntelliJ was able to run the app successfully without the fix.